# speedup my search query in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, search

I create a program that search between 20000 record.
I implement this search in

```
edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {...}
```

When user enter a character search query execute.but very slow return answer.

this is my record table :

```
id, prodname, proddet, prodid, refid
```

and this is my search query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT prodname , prodid FROM tblProd where ((prodname like '%"+name+"%') or (proddet like '%"+name+"%') and (prodname IS NOT NULL))  LIMIT 20;
```

Also my table is fts3 and use this query for search :

```
SELECT DISTINCT prodname  , prodid  FROM  tblProd where (tblProd MATCH  '"+name+"*')  LIMIT 20
```

but speed is slow like other table.

any one can help me how to speed up this search without delay.
and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you're using a `like '%...%'` query. you cannot use indexes with  those, so without fundamentally changing your search system, there is very little you can do to speed things up. e.g. change to [full text](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3) searching instead.

Comment: i cant change my search system, my table Module is fts3

Answer (score 0):

In FTS tables, the only efficient search is with MATCH.

If you don't have duplicate product IDs, remove the DISTINCT (which requires reading all rows before applying the LIMIT).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i remove DISTINCT  but speed is slow yet .